# Enormous setup time for PWM on BeagleBone Green Wireless

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, pwm

Note: the only BeagleBone tag I could find was for the Black, this is a Green Wifi, but I have no reason to believe the Green and Black behave differently in this matter. Alternate tagging recommendations welcome.

For an embedded application, I'm using a BeagleBone Green Wireless and the Adafruit python3 libraries, I'm trying to generate some PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) for audio beep alerts to the machine operator, and finding that it's taking ~240 milliseconds to setup for a PWM command, and this is just feels like a crazy long amount of time.

Minimal python code that connects the PWM pin to a speaker (via a transistor):

```
import time
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM

pwmPin = "P8_46"

PWM.start(pwmPin, duty_cycle = 50, frequency = 1000)
time.sleep(0.080)
PWM.stop(pwmPin)
```

This makes a 1000 Hz beep for 80 msec as expected, but only after a ~240 msec delay while the PWM gets setup.

To fully instrument this, I used another GPIO pin and hooked up both pins to a scope, toggling the I/O pin to help me synchronize the code with what I'm seeing.

[image: odd PWM Setup times on BeagleBone]

Upper trace is the PWM output, which is correct, and the bottom trace shows various sync pulses from the code to let me know what I'm seeing. The long 242 msec pulse (which is active only during the PWM setup statement).

This is the actual code that generated the traces:

```py
import time
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIOn
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM  as PWM

bitPin = "P8_10"    
pwmPin = "P8_46"

GPIO.setup(bitPin, GPIO.OUT)
currentBit = GPIO.input(bitPin)

def toggleBit():
    global bitPin
    global currentBit

    currentBit = not currentBit

    GPIO.output(bitPin, currentBit)

# INITIAL SYNC PULSE -- 92 microseconds
toggleBit()             
toggleBit()             

# Now generate PWM beep

toggleBit()  # rising edge of 242 msec pulse
PWM.start(pwmPin, duty_cycle = 50, frequency = 1000)
toggleBit()  # trailing edge of 242 msec pulse

time.sleep(0.080)   # beep for 80 msec

toggleBit()
PWM.stop(pwmPin)
toggleBit()
```

To rule out that python just makes *all* bit fiddling slow, just before the long 242 msec high pulse is a very short blippy sync pulse: this is the inset in the upper left of the image showing that pulse 92 microseconds. This seems entirely reasonable, so I have no explanation for the crazy slow PWM setup.

I looked at the C code in the Adafruit library, and I got the sense that there was a one-time setup cost when doing PWM, but this ~240msec thing shows up repeatedly. Changing the PWM pin didn't make any difference, nor did running as root (my non-root user is a member of the proper `pwm` and `gpio` groups). I ran the proper `config-pin` commands prior to doing all this stuff.

I'm super comfortable with Linux/C, pretty comfy w/ BeagleBone, but python is fairly new to me.

I'm stumped.

Components involved (all are the latest as far as I know):

- BeagleBone Green Wireless
- Debian Buster IoT Image 2020-04-06
- Kernel version 4.19.94-ti-r42
- Python 3.7.3
- Adafruit-BBIO 1.2.0

Comment: Have you tried doing it twice in a row? If it is a one-time setup, then the second call would be faster. Otherwise, the general idea is to do what a profiler does - isolate the line of code where most of the delay occurs (e.g. calculate difference of `time.time()` before and after), then step into the function and repeat the process.

Comment: I originally tripped across this issue by calling it twice - to generate <beep> <veryshortpause> <beep>, but that short pause turned into 250msec, meaning it's not a one-time setup.

I know how to do C level debugging at this level, but there's no chance that I'm the first person to do PWM on the BeagleBone, and it's far far more likely that I'm doing something wrong than it is that Lady Ada has gotten a widely-used library fundamentally wrong. 

Hoping somebody else has figured this out.

Comment: There are million different reasons why this could be happening, try to refrain yourself from making assumptions. For example if this library was designed to operate a fan then such delay would perfectly reasonable. Instead, measure and trace down the exact part in the library where this delay occurs and there will be your answer.

Comment: After a day of research, it's clear to me that this is an outright bug.  I filed an issue with the project: https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/350